# java.sql.SQLException: Data truncated for column 'MonthlyIncome' at row 1 error

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to update as well as save data to my database using my GUI.
My problem is, if i don't enter any data to certain textboxes which i have allowed null on my database, i get this kind of error: java.sql.SQLException: Data truncated for column 'MonthlyIncome' at row 1

Comment: `'MonthlyIncome'`? Do you using JDBC? Show your query please.

Comment: What kind of DataType does your MonthlyIncome ??

Comment: i used double as my datatype for monthlyincome

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Typically this problem occurs when you are putting in a data that is too long for the column. In this case, whatever data you are updating the 'MonthlyIncome' field with is too long.

Comment: In my case, I had a legacy application using an old version of the MySQL connector. After updating it, it worked.

Comment: It also happens if you want to store an invalid value to an enum field.

Answer (score 13):

Another reason why this error could occur is when the type of your column is an ENUM with a limited list of values but you are trying to insert something that doesnt belong in that list.

For instance, if your column type is ENUM ('XXX','YYY','ZZZ') but you are trying to insert a value 'AAA' into this column, you'll get the same error.

Comment: many thanks, at first the error didn't make sense, but thanks to you pointing that out I was able to find a typo on my table creation script. kudos!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Hibernate, then another reason might be you're missing `@Enumerated` annotation. Annotate it with your desired data type like the example below :

```
@Column(name="monthly_income")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private MonthlyIncome monthlyIncome
```

Comment: Correct answer when you are using an Enum

Answer (score 1):

If you create JPA entity and SQL table separately,

If you turned off JPA table auto-creation, check in your application.properties if there is
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none`

another reason for this error might be, in your JPA entity the particular field data type and SQL Table column data type can be different.